# Php function error (Object of class PDOStatement)

Tags: php, function, pdo

Where is your problem?

Error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

sp function in DB Class;

```
function sp()
{
    $this->baglantiAc();
    $query = $this->db->prepare("DECLARE @key nvarchar(50); EXEC [dbo].[get_next_UniqueNumber] @key_lenght = 50, @key = @key OUTPUT; SELECT @key as lkey");
    $query->execute();
    $query->nextRowset();
    $this->baglantiKapat();
    //var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $query;

}
```

I am calling the page like this, but there is an error.

```
$DB = new DB_Class();
$row = $DB->sp();
echo $row;
```

Comment: echo $row; is complete object, you cannot access direclty. check via print_r($row);

Comment: When I do print_r ($ row), the resulting query

Comment: what response you get with this: var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

Comment: I get the result I want when I use var_dump ($ query-> fetch (PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC)).

I could not get the result out of the function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to remove the comment with var_dump and see what you are getting. It seems there is something wrong with the query and I can see at least one typo with `length`.

Also, query is an object of PDOStatement which you are trying to echo.
If you want to get the response of fetch I would recommend something like this:

```
function sp()
{
     $this->baglantiAc();
     $query = $this->db->prepare("DECLARE @key nvarchar(50); EXEC [dbo].[get_next_UniqueNumber] @key_length = 50, @key = @key OUTPUT; SELECT @key as lkey");
     $query->execute();
     $query->nextRowset();
     $this->baglantiKapat();
     //var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
     $response = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     return $response;
}

$DB = new DB_Class();
$row = $DB->sp();
print_r($row);
```

Comment: OK,
display "Array ( [lkey] => 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000WE0 )"


        $DB = new DB_Class();
 $row = $DB->sp();
 foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    echo $val;
 }

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is an object of type `PDOStatement`.

Doing `$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` means `fetch results from PDOStatement`. But you **did not** assign this returned result to a variable. So your code should be:

```
    // $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    // return $query;
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}   // end of function
```