# Error: The object of class String, from mapping could not be converted to [class java.sql.Timestamp]

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, toplink

I launch a sql statement trying to get one object with a Date field and throws error. I can save without any problem in my database, but i cannot recover the data and create objects.

**Error:**

```
Exception [TOPLINK-3002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0 (Build b41-beta2 (03/30/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551744/php-function-error-object-of-class-pdostatement09/06/17 15:05:08,022000000], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [oracle.toplink.essentials.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[fecha_cambio-->SGSI_DOCUMENTOS.FECHA_CAMBIO]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(com.dominion.procop.sgsi.entidades.DocumentoOnline --> [DatabaseTable(SGSI_DOCUMENTOS)])], could not be converted to [class java.sql.Timestamp].
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ConversionException.incorrectTimestampFormat(ConversionException.java:99)
```

**Query that throws error:**

```
@NamedQuery(name="ProyContDocumentos.getDocumentosPorPC", query="SELECT p.documento FROM ProyContDocumentos p " +
        "WHERE p.idProyecto = :idProyecto AND p.idControl = :idControl ORDER BY p.idDocumento ASC"),
```

**DocumentoOnline:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SGSI_DOCUMENTOS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="DocumentoOnline.getAll", query="SELECT d FROM DocumentoOnline d ORDER BY d.id ASC")
})

public class DocumentoOnline extends EntidadBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6891627122405312774L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_documento")
    private int                     id;

    @Column(name = "titulo", nullable = false, length = 3000)
    private String                  titulo;

    @Column(name = "descripcion", nullable = false, length = 3000)
    private String                  descripcion;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date                fecha_cambio;

    @Column(name = "contenido", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    private String                  contenido;

    /*
     * GETTERS Y SETTERS
     */

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Date getFecha_cambio() {
        return fecha_cambio;
    }

    public void setFecha_cambio(Date fecha_cambio) {
        this.fecha_cambio = fecha_cambio;
    }

    public String getContenido() {
        return contenido;
    }

    public void setContenido(String contenido) {
        this.contenido = contenido;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DocumentoOnline [id=" + id + ", titulo=" + titulo + ", descripcion=" + descripcion + ", fecha_cambio="
                + fecha_cambio + ", contenido=" + contenido + "]";
    }
}
```

The database:

```
Column Name.........Data type...length..Allow Nulls
ID_DOCUMENTO........NUMBER..............false
TITULO..............VARCHAR2....4000....false
DESCRIPCION.........VARCHAR2....4000....false
FECHA_CAMBIO........VARCHAR2....1000....false
CONTENIDO...........VARCHAR2....4000....true
```

What can i do to parse that String to Date() and create my object DocumentoOnline? 
Regards.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear to me, your string has a bit more than just the timestamp in it: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551744/php-function-error-object-of-class-pdostatement09/06/17 15:05:08,022000000`. I don’t know why it includes the URL of [this question: Php function error (Object of class PDOStatement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551744/php-function-error-object-of-class-pdostatement), I suppose it comes from your database?

Comment: Maybe you should let us know what your database table (SGSI_DOCUMENTOS) looks like? Column datatypes and how the row looks when you query your Oracle database directly.

Comment: @OleV.V., updated with the rows of SGSI_DOCUMENTOS. Now i see the type of fecha_cambio is varchar2 and not timestamp...

Comment: It’s even `varchar2(1000)` — much wider than needed for a timestamp. Which value does the column hold in the row you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: Why are you storing dates/timestamps as strings in your table at all? You appear to be running into problems with implicit conversion and a difference in `NLS_NUMERIC CHARACTERS` setting, based on the comma in your string. You may be able to override that (look into your locale settings), but life would be easier if you used the right data types.

Comment: @OleV.V. just date (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss), nothing more.

Comment: @AlexPoole , i dont know why it's varchar. I modified the column type to timestamp(6) and now works perfectly!.

Answer (score 1):

The table SGSI_DOCUMENTOS was:

```
Column Name.........Data type...length..Allow Nulls
ID_DOCUMENTO........NUMBER..............false
TITULO..............VARCHAR2....4000....false
DESCRIPCION.........VARCHAR2....4000....false
FECHA_CAMBIO........VARCHAR2....1000....false
CONTENIDO...........VARCHAR2....4000....true
```

I modified the data type to FECHA_CAMBIO row with the statement:

```
alter table SGSI_DOCUMENTOS
modify 
( 
   fecha_cambio    timestamp(6)
);
```